# How to uncalibrate the compass

Tags: android, android-sensors, magnetometer

I am building an Android app (for version 8 currently) that uses the magnetic compass. In the application, I have added a check to confirm that the compass is currently giving accurate results and, if it is not, the user gets prompted to perform a 'figure of 8' calibration sequence.
In order to properly test this, I would like to UNcalibrate the compass, so that I can check that the calibration code is actually working correctly. Is there any way to do this reliably?

Related to [compass calibration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300837/compass-calibration) although that refers to a long superseded version of Android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compass calibration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300837/compass-calibration)

Answer (score 0):

If you allow the device to sit motionless for a while (with your app not reading the compass), that may do it.
You also might bring something magnetic close to it to throw the magnetometer off.
My understanding of "calibration" is as follows: the hardware (or low level drivers) know that earth's magnetic field is uniform, hence length of resulting magnetic vector should be constant regardless of device orientation.  If there is a second magnetic field which rotates *with* the device, the sum of the two fields will *not* be constant; they detect this and mathematically subtract out the second field by analyzing how the sum field is distorted.  Waving in a figure 8 provides enough sample data at various orientations to accomplish this.